# How do I manage limits.conf data using Hiera's common.yaml file?

Tags: puppet, hiera

Boss says I need to use saz-limits to manage /etc/security/limits.conf so I've installed it despite my belief that erwbgy/limits is the better option.

My problem is, he wants me to implement everything in Hiera and there are no yaml example snippets in the module or anywhere else. I have the below in my common.yaml file and of course it fails.

```
    limits::params:
      'limits-conf'
        'purge_limits_d_dir'   : false,
          'priority' : 0,
           'content'  :  "0:999999                soft    nofile           131072\n
                         0:999999                hard    nofile           131072\n
                         0:999999                soft    nproc            131072\n
                         0:999999                hard    nproc            131072\n"

0:999999                soft    nofile          131072
0:999999                hard    nofile          131072
0:999999                soft    nproc           131072
0:999999                hard    nproc           131072
```

ERROR:

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Answer (score 1):

To pass the `purge_limits_d_dir` parameter to `class limits`

```
limits::purge_limits_d_dir: false
```

As for the rest of your YAML, that does not appear to cater to **any** of the API described in the [README](https://github.com/saz/puppet-limits/blob/master/README.md). You're likely way off track.

The YAML is also malformed, so it makes sense that Hiera lookups will fail. Note that you can use JSON with Hiera if you are more comfortable with that.